# How far in advance (before the start date) can I apply for a US J1/J2 visa?

Tags: usa, j-visa

How far in advance (before the start date) can I apply for a US J1/J2 visa?

Can I apply for a US J1/J2 around 6 months ahead of the start date?

Comment: I thought there was some rule about 120 days, but I haven't found a reliable source. Ask the consulate, maybe?

Answer (score -1):

You can apply as soon as you have the required paperwork from your sponsor.